# Render in parallel view

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I'd like to render a scene in parallel view, where the camera distance is at infinity:
http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall99/cs426/lectures/view/img016.gif

In the camera setting panel I can only select "Perspective", "Orthographic" and "Panoramic".

Is a parallel view possible in Blender?
Thanks!

Comment: [Orthographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection) is a form of parallel projection. Perhaps it's what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, Orthographic is parallel